# New wording for [namespace.memdef]/1

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, using-declaration

I believe the new wording for [[namespace.memdef]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#1) tries to explain the conflict between the two declarations `using M::g;` and `void g();` in namespace `X`, but I fail to understand the relationship between this new wording and the alluded conflict.

> A declaration in a namespace `N` (excluding declarations in nested
>   scopes) whose *declarator-id* is an *unqualified-id* ([dcl.meaning]),
>   whose *class-head-name* (Clause [class]) or *enum-head-name*
>   ([dcl.enum]) is an *identifier*, or whose *elaborated-type-specifier*
>   is of the form *class-key* *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *identifier* ([dcl.type.elab]), or that is an *opaque-enum-declaration*, declares (or redeclares) its *unqualified-id* or *identifier* as a member of `N`. [ Note: An explicit instantiation ([temp.explicit]) or explicit specialization
>   ([temp.expl.spec]) of a template does not introduce a name and thus
>   may be declared using an *unqualified-id* in a member of the enclosing
>   namespace set, if the primary template is declared in an inline
>   namespace.  — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace X {
>   void f() { /* ... */ }        // OK: introduces X​::​f()
>
>   namespace M {
>     void g();                   // OK: introduces X​::​M​::​g()
>   }
>   using M::g;
>   void g();                     // error: conflicts with X​::​M​::​g()
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Even when I look at the [DR 1838](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1838) which probably gave origin to the change in this paragraph, I have some problems understanding the following sentence (emphasis is mine):

> The Standard is not clear about what happens when an entity is
>   declared but not defined in an inner namespace and declared via a
>   *using-declaration* in an outer namespace, and a **definition** of an entity with that name as an *unqualified-id* appears in the outer
>   namespace. Is this a legitimate definition of the inner-namespace
>   entity, as it would be if the definition used a *qualified-id*, or is
>   the definition a member of the outer namespace and thus in conflict
>   with the *using-declaration*? There is implementation divergence on
>   the treatment of such definitions.

The example that follows this sentence is exactly the same as the one in the paragraph `[namespace.memdef]/1`. I highlighted the word **definition** above, as there is no definition for the function `X::g()` in the alluded Example. What am I missing?

Comment: A declaration in the outer namespace already, by itself, gives rise to that issue; it's not necessary to have a definition. The resolution then applies to both cases (every definition is also a declaration).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can agree with this, but how would you interpret the new wording in the paragraph, to reach this same conclusion.

Comment: What's unclear about that wording? It doesn't mention the word "definition". DR does; the issue it raises is somewhat narrower than what the resolution ultimately addresses, is all. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of your confusion.

Comment: I'm not talking about the word definition now. How would you interpret [namespace.memdef]/1 to reach the conclusion that the declaration `void g();` in `X` conflicts with the using-declaration `using M::g;`?.

Comment: This passage confirms that `void g();` declares `X::g`, rather than `X::M::g`. At which point **[namespace.udecl]/13** kicks in: "Since a *using-declaration* is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (3.3) also apply to *using-declarations*." And then **[basic.scope.declarative]/4** talks about the same name for different things in one declarative region.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted paragraph indicates that since the outer `void g();` uses an *unqualified-id* as its *declarator-id*, it declares `g` to be a member of the outer namespace, that is, `X`.

C++17 [namespace.udecl]/14 also states as follows:

> If a function declaration in namespace scope or block scope has the same name and the same parameter-type-list (11.3.5) as a function introduced by a *using-declaration*, and the declarations do not declare the
> same function, the program is ill-formed.

So the idea behind the resolution of issue 1838 is that you now have a declaration of `g` as a member of `X`, but there's also a `g` introduced by the *using-declaration* that is a member of `X::M`. These have the same name and the same parameter-type-list, but they're not the same function, so this rule is violated, and the program is ill-formed.

I'm not sure if the wording is totally clear even after this change, though; how do we know that the two `g`'s really aren't the same function? According to C++17 [basic.link]/9,

> Two names that are the same (Clause 6) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, template or namespace if
>
> - both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same
>   translation unit; and
> - both names refer to members of the same namespace or to members, not by inheritance, of the same
>   class; and
> - when both names denote functions, the parameter-type-lists of the functions (11.3.5) are identical; and
> - when both names denote function templates, the signatures (17.5.6.1) are the same.

One could argue that since `X::M::g`  was also brought into `X` by a *using-declaration*, it is also a member of `X`, meaning that all 4 criteria are satisfied between it and the other `X::g`. (The text isn't really clear about whether a *using-declaration* declares something to be a member of the namespace it appears in.) So I would argue that the issue was not totally resolved then.

However, in the C++23 draft, it really is resolved. See N4928 [basic.scope.scope]/2.4, [basic.scope.scope]/5, [basic.link]/8, [namespace.udecl]/10.